# Can I still get the Haunted Metal Scrap?

Tags: team-fortress-2

Is [Haunted Metal Scrap](http://wiki.teamfortress.com/wiki/Haunted_Metal_Scrap) being awarded during the lead-up to this year's Halloween event? Is haunted scrap under the same restrictions as haunted gifts (i.e. they're only awarded during a special time of year)?

I've attempted to melee the Horsemann a couple times but I haven't had any success.

Comment: Well, the Haunted Gifts (and related achievements) are functioning properly. While I, too, have yet to melee the HHH, I would *assume* so.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The Haunted Scrap can be earned year-round  As of 2014, Halloween mode is automatically activated on Halloween maps in order to get their bosses to spawn.  However, the haunted gifts only drop during the Halloween event.  Starting with the Halloween 2011 update, gifts will only drop on servers [registered with Valve](https://support.steampowered.com/kb_article.php?ref=2825-AFGJ-3513#how).  This is going from a long conversation thread on the hlds_linux mailing list:

> We're going to be launching some new Halloween content in the near future and wanted to give you all a quick heads-up.  There will be random gift drops, but this year we are requiring that participants register their servers.  If you choose not to register, you can still run the Halloween maps, but no gifts will drop on your server.

The easiest (and expected) way to get the Haunted Metal Scrap is to melee the Horsemann while he's doing his death scream 2 seconds before he dies.  I'm not sure if Meleeing him at any other time will award the achievement.

The problem is staying alive and being close enough to melee him.  The easiest classes to do this with are Demoman (with one of the charging shields) and Scout.

His death scream is heard at 1:18 in this video:

Comment: Interesting... looks like I'll have to get my servers registered finally

Comment: I confirm that meleeing him at any other time won't award the achievement.

Comment: I was able to get it from a trade server running the map `trade_minecraft_b38` on January 2012. Maybe that info could be relevant to someone.

Answer (score 3):

The first time I killed the Horsemann, I didn't get the *Gored!* achievement or the Haunted Metal Scrap. However, the second time I got both, so I can verify that you **can** obtain both the achievement and the item, just that there's not a 100% chance of getting it.

Answer (score 2):

you need to meele him AND survive.  so hit him and run to base so you don't get killed.  also I heard it only comes "clean" (tradable) if you get it during or around Halloween.  I got mine some random time this year and its dirty. :(

Answer (score 1):

You can only get it once per account, not once per year, so if you've already achieved the achievement *Gored!*, you can't "still get it" because you already would (should) have.

If you can't find the metal in your bags, did you already craft it into the Horseless Headless Horsemann's Headtaker or a fashionable festive hat?

Comment: Once per account? I doubt that.

Comment: @BlaXpirit: No, he's right.  You can't get it again.  Then again, Blizzard hasn't yet added this year's Halloween map and its associated drops.

Comment: @Powerlord: "Blizzard"!? Now that's weird.

Comment: @BlaXpirit: I was talking to people about WoW's ridiculous upcoming expansion, so Blizzard comes to the keyboard quite easily.  Oddly, I managed to get the right company (Valve) in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

I got it 15 minutes ago, so they work.

However, I hit him with melee numerous times (and stayed alive until he died) without getting it. The only difference now was that I hit him with melee and he died shortly afterwards (mine was not the killing blow though)

Comment: If only I could figure out what to do with it now...

Comment: The link in the question will tell you!

Answer (score 0):

It must be the last hit, not the killing blow. You can hit him when he is doing his death scream though, but you just have to be the last to hit him. You get it once per account and you have to survive if you are the last hit

Answer (score -3):

You can still get Haunted Scrap through trades, if you use gift wrap on it and trade it to someone.